# Overlapping table contents, how to wrap the cell contents

Tags: latex

I am trying to code for a table but some of the column contents are overlapping. I have pasted the full code here. Please help me as I am new to latex.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,thmsa]{article}

\usepackage{multirow}





\begin{document}




\begin{table}
 \caption{Example to compute the required figures}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{0.05\linewidth}|p{0.05\linewidth}|p{0.05\linewidth}|p{0.05\linewidth}|p{0.05\linewidth}|p{0.05\linewidth}|p{0.05\linewidth}|p{0.05\linewidth}|p{0.05\linewidth}|p{0.05\linewidth}|}
    \hline
    % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
      \multirow{2}{*}{Current Phase}  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{First variable} &    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Second Variable} & DIfference in Phase & Total of the first variable & Growth inforst variable &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{CHange in second variable}\\
\cline{2-5}
    & Old & New& $Lab$ &    $Lab$   &&&&&\\
 \hline
$TP0$ & 200 &    400  & 10&    0&   &  10& NA& Old&    New\\
\hline
$TP1$& 400& 400  &10& 0&  $TP0$ to $TP1$& 200& 10& 0&  0\\
\hline
$TP2$ & 200& 400& 0&  10&  $TP0$ to $TP2$& 200& 10& -10& 10\\
\hline
  \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
 \label{Toy_exp}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: please make a compilable [mre], e.g. a small but compilable document including a documentclass and the necessary packages

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I have made the changes and created a minimal reproducible example. Please help me to figure out the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using p columns for your table which allow automatic line breaks, but if you the go ahead and use `\multicolumn{2}{c}{...}` you are overwriting this with a centred cell without linebreaks.

If you use fixed width columns instead you get linebreaks (although not pretty because your page is much to small for this table layout).

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,thmsa]{article}

\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}




\begin{table}
 \caption{Toy example to depict the STI calculation}
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{|p{0.1\linewidth}|p{0.05\linewidth}|p{0.05\linewidth}|p{0.05\linewidth}|p{0.05\linewidth}|p{0.1\linewidth}|p{0.1\linewidth}|p{0.1\linewidth}|p{0.05\linewidth}|p{0.05\linewidth}|}
    \hline
    % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
      \multirow{2}{=}{Time Period}  & \multicolumn{2}{p{0.1\linewidth}|}{Labour Productivity} &    \multicolumn{2}{p{0.1\linewidth}|}{Labour force} & Change in Period &  Aggregate Productivity & Growth in Productivity &   \multicolumn{2}{p{0.1\linewidth}|}{Change in Labour Force}\\
\cline{2-5}
    & Trad. & Mod. & $L_t$ &    $L_m$   &&&&&\\
 \hline
$T_0$ & 10 &    20  & 1&    0&   &  10& NA& Trad.&    Mod.\\
\hline
$T_1$&  20& 20  &1& 0&  $T_0$ to $T_1$& 20& 10& 0&  0\\
\hline
$T_2$ & 10& 20& 0&  1&  $T_0$ to $T_2$& 20& 10& -1& 1\\
\hline
  \end{tabular}
 \label{Toy_exp}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you give your table enough room to breath, e.g. by adding `\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}`, you get a much nicer result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz. I feel really good today, as you spent your valuable time for helping me. May the almighty God bless you abundantly :)

Comment: @Mazreen May I suggest http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf as some reading material on how to produce really professional looking tables?

Comment: Thank you very much @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz. I sincerely appreciate your help for my problem. Thank you for your time and consideration in addressing the issue. 

Regarding the reading material, I value the effort that you put into the matter, and I am deeply moved and profoundly grateful for all you have done. Thank you samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz :) once again.